# Mac won't boot after Mojave 10.14.6 update

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, startup, software-update

here's hoping that someone may be able to help. I updated my Mac to Mojave 10.14.6, from 10.14.4, I think, and when I returned to the Mac, was greeted by the message that no disk could be found, and the Mac would not boot.

I have been able to boot from an external drive, and can see my Fusion drive from Disk Utility, but it won't mount and Disk Utility won't repair it. I've tried re-installing Mojave on the Fusion drive, but the Mojave installer won't see the disk. I have scanned the drives using DiskDrill, and it has found the data on the drive. I've tried recovering the data, and have only been partially successful. Some of the files seem ok, whereas others are unreadable.

Is there any way to repair the drive so that it is bootable again, without erasing it and starting again. Any help gratefully received. I've run various commands in Terminal, and pasted the results below.

I am in the UK, so may not be able to answer immediately, but I will monitor the thread, and respond as quickly as possible. Thank you for any assistance.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         2.0 TB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.1 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            1.3 TB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.6 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      5.8 GB     disk2s4
```

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.4

```
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.


 Expert command (? for help): p
    Disk /dev/disk0: 29622272 sectors, 113.0 GiB
    Sector size (logical): 4096 bytes
    Disk identifier (GUID): 7FF1686B-E0C2-48EB-A216-15A50CF266D6
    Partition table holds up to 128 entries
    Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
    First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 29622266
    Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
    Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

    Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
       1               6           76805   300.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
       2           76806        29622266   112.7 GiB   AF0A  CS Header

    Expert command (? for help): o

    Disk size is 29622272 sectors (113.0 GiB)
    MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
    MBR partitions:

    Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
       1                     1     29622271   primary     0xEE
```

The output of `diskutil verifyVolume disk2`:

```
Started file system verification on disk2
Verifying storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/disk1s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the fusion superblock
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking the Fusion data structures
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by hfs_convert (945.200.129) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.260.7)
Checking the object map
error: (oid 0x4000000235694) om: btn: invalid o_cksum (0x515aa86f36bcc266)
Object map is invalid
The volume /dev/disk1s2 could not be verified completely
Storage system check exit code is 8
Error: -69716: Storage system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8
```

Comment: Please boot to your external disk (hopefully also Mojave), verify the internal APFS Container (here: `diskutil verifyVolume disk2`) and add the Terminal output as text to your question.

Comment: Added Terminal output as requested - thank you.